# python - weird results with exponent operator in idle

Tags: python, math, operators, exponential

I'm getting a strange result when squaring -1 in idle.  What's going on?

Unexpected result:

```
>>>| -1 ** 2
>>>| -1
```

Expected result:

```
>>>| pow(-1,2)
>>>| 1

>>>| my_var = -1
>>>| my_var **= 2
>>>| my_var
>>>| 1
```

Comment: what about : `(-1) ** 2`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Operator precedence (the `-` is a unary minus operator):

```
>>> -1 ** 2
-1
>>> -(1 ** 2)
-1
>>> (-1) ** 2
1
```

Comment: duh! the negative is also an operator **facepalm**

Comment: fwiw I agree this is confusing and my initial reaction is that it's silly to have the precedence in that order, although I'm sure there's a good reason for it in some PEP and/or math textbook :)

Comment: @Samwise Not sure about a _good_ reason, but most mathematicians expect `-x²` (for example in the context of a polynomial like `-x² + x + 3`) to mean `-(x²)` rather than `(-x)²`.

Comment: Good point!  It's just the case of int literals where it comes across as nonsensical.

Comment: If `-1` were parsed as `int("-1")` rather than `int.__neg__(int("1"))` there'd be no problem.  :)

Answer (score 3):

This happens occurs because of Precedence Operators:

1. `()`    Parentheses
2. `**`    Exponent
3. `+x`, `-x`, `~x`    Unary plus, Unary minus, Bitwise NOT
4. `*`, `/`, `//`, `%` Multiplication, Division, Floor division, Modulus
5. `+`, `-`    Addition, Subtraction

you can get what you want like below, In The question first `**` then compute `Unary minus` for solving you need to use higher precedence like `()` Parentheses.

```
>>> (-1) ** 2
1
```